# Ruby on Rails - devise not making the user log in when the user is not logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am learning Ruby and Devise and for some reason users who are not logged in, are not getting redirected to be logged in.

Here is the route I have:

```
  scope :module => :mobile, :as => :mobile do
    constraints(:subdomain => /m/) do
      devise_for :users, :path => "", :path_names => { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout", :sign_up => "signup" }, :controllers => {:sessions => "sidebar/sessions"}

      resources :home

      resources :disclosures # Will have new, get, look up a disclosure

      devise_for :users, :path => "", :path_names =>
          { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout", :sign_up => "signup" }

    end
  end
```

and here is my controller:

```
class Mobile::HomeController < ApplicationController
  layout "mobile/application"
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

  def create

  end
end
```

Any idea why the user isn't being redirected to log in? Right now, the user is just being shown the page where he can only see if authenticated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

to

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```